# Need help in my rock paper and scissors game javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When the user and computer tied, it keeps telling me that I LOST instead of being tied.

```
<html>
<head>        
    <title>Rock, Paper and Scissors</title>        
</head>
<body>
    <p>Rock, Paper and Scissors!</p>        
    <input type="text" id ="textChoice">        
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>        
    <p id="paragraphChoice"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">            
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {                
            var computerChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];            
            var computerGuess = 
                computerChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoice.length)];                
            var userGuess = document.getElementById("textChoice").value;

            if (userGuess === computerGuess) {                    
                document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML = 
                    "You tied! The computer choose "+ computerGuess; //Both tied!                   
            }

            if (userGuess === "rock") {                    
                if (computerGuess === "scissors") {
                    //rock wins
                    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML =
                        "You won! The computer choose "+ computerGuess;                        
                } else {
                    //paper wins
                    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML =
                        "You lost! The computer choose "+ computerGuess;                        
                }                    
            }

            if (userGuess === "paper") {                    
                if (computerGuess === "rock") {
                    //rock wins
                    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML =
                        "You won! The computer choose "+ computerGuess;                        
                } else {
                    //scissors wins
                    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML =
                        "You lost! The computer choose "+ computerGuess;                        
                }                    
            }

            if (userGuess === "scissors") {                    
                if (computerGuess === "paper") {                        
                    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML = 
                        "You won! The computer choose "+ computerGuess;                        
                } else {                        
                    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML = 
                        "You lost! The computer choose "+ computerGuess;                        
                }                    
            }                
        };        
    </script>        
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't learned functions so far, the if statements are pretty messy(well that's what I think).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

when you reach an answer you are done: if 2===2 then *finished*. do not check other possibilities. so

```
if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
    document.getElementById("paragraphChoice").innerHTML = 
        "You tied! The computer choose "+ computerGuess; //Both tied!

    // you are done. return.
    return;
}
```

if you do not tell the program you are done, it will continue checking all the other `if-then` blocks and the last one will print to the page. You will have to add a `return` inside each `if then` block.